# Xcode armv7 issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, parsekit

My application builds fine for the simulator but not the device:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/newuser/Downloads/release-1.5-tag/build/Release-iphoneos/parsekit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

I'm using the ParseKit lib which doesn't seem to like being mixed with armv7.

I think I have to do some form of linking with the library? But how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have linked the library, only it is not built for armv7.

The ParseKit Xcode project has a target called ParseKitMobile, which is built for armv7. Try using that.

[image]

You could also try changing the "Base SDK" setting to iOS, that should give you arm options for the architecture.

Comment: It says the architecture for Parsekit uses Mac OS so the options are different, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that you'll have to re-compile ParseKit for the `armv7` architecture. Are you following the [instructions for iPhone](http://parsekit.com/iphone.html) on the ParseKit homepage? It does not seem to mention armv7 explicitly, but I guess if you add `parsekit.a` as a target from ParseKit's project file to your own project file, then XCode should recognize that the target has to be re-built for `armv7`.

Note: the instructions are for XCode 3 and I guess you are using XCode 4, but the whole idea should be the same.

Comment: I followed that and it always worked, but now when I try to deploy to the device the error kicks in. How can I recompile parsekit for armv7? it offers Intel options.

Answer (score 1):

`parsekit.a` is a static library and it has to be statically linked with binaries having the same ABI. So you have following options:

1. Build you code for the same ABI as `parsekit.a` has;
2. Build `parsekit.a` for the armv7;
3. Build parsekit as a shared library;
4. Write wrapper for `parsekit.a` that will be built as shared library and expose all the API you need.

Comment: Thanks, is step 2 a simple one? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with xcode but it should be done with single option because it is controlled by single compiler flag. Normally any code that compiles for armv5 or armv6 can be compiled for armv7.