# getting xcode error when creating release build for appstore

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

i am facing problem for last day i have seen many answers on stackoverflow and other sites but can't work for me to fix this issue . the error is when i creating releease build for apptore. and trying to uploading my app on appstore getting this error

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
```

after doing lot of effort , i am not able to fix it.

Comment: Duplicate: Here you have an answer with image: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214789/xcode-armv7-issue

Comment: yes sir i check that answer but it not work for me

Comment: Make sure you did that in all Targets

Comment: their is only 1 target in my project

Comment: Can you make a screenshot from your config ? Make sure both: Architectures and Valid Architectures are opened and visible

Comment: Well, without simple "Please" or "Thank you", it think no-one will try to help you further if you even don't provide enough information

Comment: its require atleast 10 reputation to upload image

Answer (score 0):

- Open project settings (Select project in project navigator)
- Switch to **Build Settings** tab
- Check these settings:

  - **Architectures**: should say `Standard (armv7, armv7s)` (This should be default option you can select from the list. If not, set it manually to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`
  - Valid architectures: `armv7 armv7s` Again, these should be default. If not, edit it manually (add those two values as the separate values in the list)

The above are valid settings of one of my apps in the AppStore. Should be OK for the following:

- Base SDK: `Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)`
- Deployment target: `5.0`

Im not sure, but this could be the problem as it often is

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE POST THE SCREENSHOT FROM YOUR CONFIG TO GET BETTER IDEA. LUKAS SETTINGS SHOULD WORK.